# IllegalArgumentException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.LocalStrings != com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.LocalStrings

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

In my web-application, I am contacting a Web-Service (using JAX-WS) but I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AttachmentUnmarshallerImpl.<clinit>(AttachmentUnmarshallerImpl.java:55)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder$DocLit.readResponse(ResponseBuilder.java:500)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:242)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:210)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:103)
        ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.LocalStrings != com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.LocalStrings
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:314)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.AttachmentPartImpl.<clinit>(AttachmentPartImpl.java:71)
    ... 189 more
```

This happen on my machine, when I run my application in Eclipse...

What can be the source of this error?

I was suspecting this [Oracle Java bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6741342), but I am running my web-application in Tomcat 5.5 and Java 1.6.0_18, as shown in my `System.properties`:

```
java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
sun.boot.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\bin
java.vm.version = 16.0-b13
java.runtime.version = 1.6.0_18-b07
java.version = 1.6.0_18
```

Comment: The bug you refer to is detected in 1.6.0_4 and not yet fixed. Why wouldn't you expect it to be present in your environment?

Comment: @jarnbjo Just because this problem only occured in *my* environment, and not on others environment (Development, Homologation, and so on). This was due to a problem in my `saaj-impl-1.3.jar` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved. This was due to a third-party dependency, `saaj-impl-1.3.jar` which was slightly different in my environment than in the other "official" environments...

Comment: hey, how did you fix it? I am having the same problem

Comment: @Ashish try to change the version of your `saaj-impl` library. Or at least, look into your JAR file if you have `META-INF/services/javax.xml.soap.***Factory` files.

Comment: Hi. thanks for the reply. Yes, the above issue is fixed now. By the way I am not able to run Metro 2.1 in weblogic. When i run web service it uses jax-ws from weblogic instead of the metro 2.1. Please help.

Comment: @Ashish Create a new question with all the details (error messages, etc.)

Comment: Here's my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400334/how-to-run-metro-web-services-in-weblogic-10-3-5 No answers yet. Trying since last three days. :-(

Comment: Hi same problem updated my saaj-impl to the last version and works. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I was not using saaj-impl... but in my case, putting the webservices-api.jar (2.0 version from Metro) in /lib/endorsed worked.

Just in case it helps someone...