# Problem using jax-ws

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, saaj

I'm using JAX-WS to contact Web-Service and get the following error:

```
com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.LocalStrings != com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.LocalStrings
```

Searched a bit for this kind of problem and found this
http://forums.java.net/node/678924
But that just won't work in my case.
There seems to be problem with jdk6(I'm currently using java(build 1.6.0_22-b04)) 
and saaj-impl(currently using saaj-impl-1.3.2.jar).
Apparently jdk6 has its own saaj but in another package(internal added)
and it battles with saaj-impl(imported by maven2).

Could it be a problem for using Tomcat6 also(just wondering, not sure at all :)).

If there is more code or config files needed I will provide them.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Milos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you have to do is put the latest version in the java endorsed directory. Put it in both the JDK and JRE installation. If you are using Tomcat it also has its endorsed directory.

Yes jax-ws on jdk 6 is a real pain, they tried to have it embedded for use out of the box but the moment u need to update something everything breaks. Alternatively try CXF, its not plainsailing either but tends to suffer less from these kinds of conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply jbx! I asssume you are suggesting to put saaj-impl.jar in endorsed directory of JDK and JRE, also Tomcat. The thing is that Tomcat6 doesn't have directory called endorsed or such(unlike Tomcat5 that has /common/endorsed), can you guide how to do that, should I create the directory manually and where(I assume in $CATALINA_HOME)? Also where to put it in JRE and JDK, there is no such directories there. Thanks in advance!

Comment: i doubt how much of a difference that would make since Tomcat already makes use of the saaj-impl that's present within your jdk. as an afterthought - is your Tomcat actually using a compatible JRE? check what JAVA_HOME is Tomcat pointing to, and is it the same one you compiled against.

Comment: Tomcat is using (build 1.6.0_06-b02), sorry, my mistake cause I previously wrote that it uses (build 1.6.0_22-b04). That is the only java installed. I'm not sure is there any difference because it is jdk6 after all. Should I put this jar in lib folder?

Comment: From Tomcat 6 onwards they removed it from common/endorsed and now its just directly under the base directory. Normally its not there, but you can create it and it should work because the default startup scripts include: ${CATALINA_BASE}/endorsed .

You can check ${CATALINA_BASE}/bin/setclasspath.sh to ensure that %{CATALINA_BASE}/endorsed is the right path for the endorsed libraries.

Comment: I just created and set paths to $CATALINA_HOME/endorsed, copied the jar there but error stays the same. Any ideas or suggestions? Maybe using jdk1.5 will help, did jax-ws worked ok with that version of Java?

Comment: like i mentioned - Tomcat already picks up/resolves the dependencies from your JRE, so you do NOT need to add the SDK jar files to the endorsed lib. For now, i can suggest you try 2 things - [1] point Tomcat to use build 1.6.0_22-b04 [or re-compile your code w/ 1.6.0_06-b02], and [2] compile your code w/ 1.5 and point your Tomcat to use that as well.

Comment: Unless this is a small throw away project I wouldnt use 1.5. 1.5 is officially already end of life which means your application would remain stuck there without the capability to be upgraded.
I would check that the JRE you're using for tomcat also has the right saaj-impl. You might have more than one installation and Tomcat is using a different one. Also check that you do not have some other dependency which is also including an older version of saaj-impl in the classpath.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889087/illegalargumentexception-com-sun-xml-internal-messaging-saaj-soap-localstrings

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. Turning back to jdk1.5 didn't work, just threw another exception. Problem was solved by upgrading java6 to latest version 1.6.0_23, I guess 1.6.0_06 had some issues working with jax-ws. Also I put saaj-impl-1.3.1.jar in endorsed directory($CATALINA_HOME/endorsed).