# How to invoke metro web services in weblogic 10.3.5?

Tags: web-services, jaxb, jax-ws, weblogic-10.x, java-metro-framework

I have two web applications (bot of them ear files) deployed on the weblogic server. One of them is a web service application and the other is a web service client.

METRO is used for the web services. The web service application is running properly.

When I try to deploy the web service client application, I am getting the following error.

```
    <Dec 14, 2011 9:51:25 AM GMT+05:30> <Error> <WLSS.Setup> <BEA-331210> <Skip SIP related logic, because error occurs when parsing sip related annotatio
ns of "DIMeX2"
com.bea.wcp.sip.engine.server.setup.SipAnnotationParsingException:
    at com.bea.wcp.sip.engine.server.setup.SipAnnotationData.<init>(SipAnnotationData.java:146)
    at com.bea.wcp.sip.util.DeploymentUtil.getOrCreateAnnotationData(DeploymentUtil.java:70)
    at com.bea.wcp.sip.util.DeploymentUtil.isSipModule(DeploymentUtil.java:96)
    at com.bea.wcp.sip.engine.server.SipServerTailModule$1.visit(SipServerTailModule.java:127)
    at com.bea.wcp.sip.engine.server.SipServerTailModule.visitAllContexts(SipServerTailModule.java:112)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class com.sun.codemodel.writer.FilterCodeWriter has interface com.sun.codemodel.CodeWriter as super
 class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
<Dec 14, 2011 9:51:26 AM GMT+05:30> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "dimex" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "/DIMeX2".
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotati
onHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean w
ith name 'auditLogController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
: Could not autowire field: com.dimex.services.UserService com.dimex.controllers.AuditLogController.userService; nested exception is org.springframewo
rk.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is or
g.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.dimex.services.client.UserServiceWS_Service]: Constructor th
rew exception; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl could not
be instantiated: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'auditLogController': Injection of autowired depende
ncies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.dimex.services.UserService co
m.dimex.controllers.AuditLogController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean w
ith name 'userService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
 instantiate bean class [com.dimex.services.client.UserServiceWS_Service]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigura
tionError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProc
essor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.dimex.services.UserService com.dimex.controllers.Aud
itLogController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService':
 Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class
 [com.dimex.services.client.UserServiceWS_Service]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws
.spi.Provider: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostP
rocessor.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProc
essor.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of resource dependencies fa
iled; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.dimex.services.client.UserServic
eWS_Service]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider com.sun.xml.ws
.spi.ProviderImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:3
00)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.dimex.services.client.UserServiceWS_Service]: C
onstructor threw exception; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderIm
pl could not be instantiated: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$WebServiceRefElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostP
rocessor.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl could not be instantiated: java.la
ng.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.getProviderUsingServiceLoader(Provider.java:146)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.getProviderUsingServiceLoader(Provider.java:146)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Error creating JAXBContext for W3CEndpointReference.
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl$2.run(ProviderImpl.java:261)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl$2.run(ProviderImpl.java:257)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.getEPRJaxbContext(ProviderImpl.java:256)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.<clinit>(ProviderImpl.java:90)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same XML type name "address". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference$Address
        at public com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference$Address com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReferenc
e.addr
        at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference$Address
        at private javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference$Address javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference.address
        at javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference
Two classes have the same XML type name "elements". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference$Elements
        at public com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference$Elements com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReferen
ce.referenceProperties
        at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference$Elements
        at private javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference$Elements javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference.referenceParameters
        at javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference

    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:472)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1140)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

I cant figure out what I am doing wrong especially when I am able to run the web service application with METRO in it properly.

I have spent like days on it with no solution.

Please help.

Comment: What version of metro is in question?

Comment: @Vadzim version of metro we are using is metro 2.1.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have

> Caused By: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class
>   com.sun.codemodel.writer.FilterCodeWriter has interface
>   com.sun.codemodel.CodeWriter as super class

This looks like you have several versions of the same library on classpath.

`com.sun.codemodel` belongs to JAXB. Ensure that JAXB api and implementation jars' versions match. Remove obsolete doubles if any (including the JAXB bundled with WebLogic).
Also check that all jaxb, jax-ws and wsit jars match the versions of the [latest metro release](http://metro.java.net/2.1.1/).

This can resolve the next exceptions too. 
If not, continue further.

Secondly you have this relevant quote form stacktrace:

> Caused By: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Error creating
>   JAXBContext for W3CEndpointReference.
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl$2.run(ProviderImpl.java:261)
>   Caused By: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of
>   IllegalAnnotationExceptions Two classes have the same XML type name
>   "address". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
>       this problem is related to the following location:
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference$Address
>           at public com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference$Address
>   com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference.addr
>           at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference
>       this problem is related to the following location:
>           at javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference$Address
>           at private javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference$Address
>   javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference.address
>           at javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference

This means that somehow both classes [W3CEndpointReference](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.xml.ws/jaxws-api/2.2.5/javax/xml/ws/wsaddressing/W3CEndpointReference.java#W3CEndpointReference.0address) and [MemberSubmissionEndpointReference](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt/2.2.5/com/sun/xml/ws/developer/MemberSubmissionEndpointReference.java#MemberSubmissionEndpointReference.0addr) participate in creation of the same JAXBContext under the same namespace.
Actually these classes have different NSes in code as can be seen at the end of the above links.
Examine client's wsdl if it has both `xmlns:samens="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"` and `xmlns:samens="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"`.
Experiment to remove notion of `"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"` at all.

If nothing helps you can debug it with metro sources. It can be even a bug in jaxb or metro.

But more likely the cause is in an old namespace-unaware version of JAXB that sneaked in classpath.